# Can you create a singleton in Julia?

Tags: julia

I know that Julia does not have OOP but that multiple dispatch enables similar ideas. Given how seemingly contentious the use of singletons are in Python, I am wondering if there is a similar idea Julia (i.e. a struct that can only be instantiated once).

I am wondering if there's a way to have the constructor keep track of the number of times an object was instantiated with a global var or something like that? Or it's altogether not be possible?

Comment: As for the second question, this is a bit involved, as the "singletonness" is ensured by `new`; if you increase a global counter in the inner constructor, it will count false instances. You could keep a global `IdDict{YourType, ()}`. Seems unnecessary, though, if singleton structs already work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main way people make singletons in Julia is to define an empty struct (which means that it has 0 size), and define methods that return information for it.

```
struct Singleton
end
data(::Singleton) = "whatever you want it to do"
```

etc.

Comment: How is member data persisted between the method calls?

Comment: This pattern is more designed for immutable singletons, in which case data is persisted in the definition of the functions on the type

Answer (score 5):

From [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/183864881X), a singleton can be defined as a type without fields:

```
struct MySingleton end

julia> MySingleton() === MySingleton()
true
```

You can also use `Val`, which can receive any value (of bit type):

```
julia> Val(1) === Val(1)
true

julia> Val(:foo) === Val(:foo)
true
```

using `Val` you can write something like this:

```
julia> do_something(::Val{:asymbol}) = println("foo")

julia> do_something(::Val{:anothersymbol}) = println("bar")

julia> do_something(s::String) = do_something(Val{Symbol(s)})

julia> do_something("asymbol")
foo
```

The definition of `Val` is:

```
struct Val{x} end
```

So, for a more clear readability of your code, you could define your own singleton type as, for example:

```
struct Command{x} end
```

Comment: It needs to be an immutable struct though, IIRC.